Salesforce Code Analyzer Issues and False-positive documentation
I am preparing for the security review. I have resolved all issues from Checkmarx and I have resolved almost all the errors from the Salesforce Code Analyzer report. There are only 6 items left from the design category.

Do these problems need to be resolved? Do they need to be included in the false-positive documentation?

First, they're likely not false positives. You probably have some complicated code that could be refactored to minimize the complexity of your code. However, that said, design category warnings won't fail a security review. These are informational messages that your code is complicated, but not a security concern. There's no need to report these in the false positive documentation.

Thank you!
Do you know whether false-positive documentation is only about security errors? For example, I have another issue related to performance that cannot be resolved, and I'm unsure whether it's worth including it in the false-positive documentation or not.

@Nazar Anything that's performance or security related should be addressed in the false positive report. For example, SOQL in loops, or XSS attack vectors.
